# How to get count of customer first time orders?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that needs to be corrected. So right now I have 90% of what I need but this last step has been giving me trouble. I know on 1996-07-04 employee #5 visited my site for the first time, and rightfully get the first timer count as 1. On 1996-07-11 I know employee #5 visited the site again but we do not want to count him again.

```
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderDate,
    COUNT(OrderDetails.OrderDetailID) AS NumSessions, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.EmployeeID)
FROM OrderDetails
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON OrderDetails.OrderID=Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.OrderDate    



EXPECTED:
DATE    NumSessions FirstTimers
1996-07-04  3   1
1996-07-11  3   0

ACTUAL:
DATE    NumSessions FirstTimers
1996-07-04  3   1
1996-07-11  3   1
```

Comment: Use `HAVING` to filter the results after a `GROUP BY`.  Be more details in your expected results. Some sample  input data would help too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (I can't guarantee it's syntactically correct, though):

```
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderDate,
    COUNT(OrderDetails.OrderDetailID) AS NumSessions,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.EmployeeID WHERE Orders.OrderDate = (
        SELECT MIN(b.OrderDate) FROM Orders b WHERE Orders.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID)
    )
FROM OrderDetails
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON OrderDetails.OrderID=Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.OrderDate
```

But I don't know how this would do performance-wise. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated.  One method is to use a subquery to calculate the first order date and to use that in the logic:

```
SELECT o.OrderDate,
       COUNT(od.OrderDetailID) AS NumSessions, 
       SUM( o.OrderDate = oe.FirstOrderDate ) as FirstTimers
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
     OrderDetails od
     ON O.OrderId = od.OrderId LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT o.EmloyeeID, MIN(OrderDate) as FirstOrderDate
      FROM Orders o 
      GROUP BY OrderDate
     ) o
     ON oe.EmployeeId = o.EmployeeId
GROUP BY o.OrderDate
```